I'm using realm to fetch data from MongoDB using OrderedRealmCollection but getting nothing
On logging i found that i'm getting an empty list
I'm a beginner, so please let me know what mistakes I made and I really need get this working.
package com.example.hospital;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.activity.EdgeToEdge;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.constraintlayout.helper.widget.Carousel;
import androidx.core.graphics.Insets;
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat;
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.hospital.ui.main.DoctorAdapter;

import org.bson.Document;

import io.realm.OrderedRealmCollection;
import io.realm.Realm;
import io.realm.RealmAsyncTask;
import io.realm.RealmConfiguration;
import io.realm.mongodb.App;
import io.realm.mongodb.AppConfiguration;
import io.realm.mongodb.Credentials;
import io.realm.mongodb.User;
import io.realm.mongodb.mongo.MongoClient;
import io.realm.mongodb.mongo.MongoCollection;
import io.realm.mongodb.mongo.MongoDatabase;

public class docselect extends AppCompatActivity {
    String Appid = "appid";
    App app;
    Realm realm;
    DoctorAdapter adapter;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    @SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        EdgeToEdge.enable(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_docselect);
        try {
            Realm.init(this);
            RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                    .schemaVersion(1)
                    .migration(new MyRealmMigration())
                    .build();
            Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);
            realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("DocSelectActivity", "Error initializing Realm", e);
            Toast.makeText(docselect.this,"Error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        app = new App(new AppConfiguration.Builder(Appid).build());
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        setupRecyclerView();

    }
    private void setupRecyclerView() {
        OrderedRealmCollection<Doctor> doctors = realm.where(Doctor.class).findAll();
        Log.d("DoctorAdapter", "Number of doctors: " + doctors.size());
        adapter = new DoctorAdapter(doctors);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (realm != null) {
            realm.close();
        }
    }

}

Doctor class (it was provided by MongoDB itself for the specified schema, means it is auto generated i just copy pasted it).
package com.example.hospital;

import io.realm.RealmObject;
import io.realm.annotations.PrimaryKey;
import io.realm.annotations.Required;

import org.bson.types.ObjectId;

public class Doctor extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    @Required
    private ObjectId _id;

    private String emp_id;

    private String name;

    private String specialisation;

    // Standard getters & setters
    public ObjectId getId() { return _id; }
    public void setId(ObjectId _id) { this._id = _id; }

    public String getEmpId() { return emp_id; }
    public void setEmpId(String emp_id) { this.emp_id = emp_id; }

    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

    public String getSpecialisation() { return specialisation; }
    public void setSpecialisation(String specialisation) { this.specialisation = specialisation; }
}

DoctorAdapter class
package com.example.hospital.ui.main;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.hospital.Doctor;
import com.example.hospital.R;

import io.realm.OrderedRealmCollection;
public class DoctorAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DoctorAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private OrderedRealmCollection<Doctor> data;

    public DoctorAdapter(OrderedRealmCollection<Doctor> data) {
        this.data = data;
        setHasStableIds(true); // If your Doctor model has a primary key
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_doctor, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Doctor doctor = data.get(position);
        holder.textViewName.setText(doctor.getName());
        holder.textViewSpecialisation.setText(doctor.getSpecialisation());
        // Bind other details here
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data != null ? data.size() : 0;
    }

    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView textViewName;
        TextView textViewSpecialisation;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textViewName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
            textViewSpecialisation = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewSpecialisation);
        }
    }
}


I read the documentation but that was too complex and didn't helped me much.
My database name is maindb and collection name is doctors
I also thought of using queryfilter but ditched the idea thing of that being too nasty, if that would be a better way please let me know.

To understand the problem, we need the Doctor and DoctorAdapter classes.
Edit your question by adding the above classes

Welcome to SO. One of the keys to successful programming is troubleshooting the code. It's especially important here on SO as it helps to narrow the specific line that's isn't working. The first step is to do some basic troubleshooting by adding a breakpoint and stepping through the code line by line, inspecting the vars and code execution until you spot something unexpected. You may discover the issue yourself by doing that. If not update your question with where the code goes wrong - which line, what's expected and what you're seeing. I also encourage you to start with the code in the docs.

@Jay actually i'm way too confused, so uploaded the whole code, and speaking of breakpoints, there is no error in code the app is compiling and running successfully but all i'm getting is an empty list.

That's a lot of code for us to parse through without narrowing down where it goes wrong. Stepping through the code line by line will narrow down where the issue is. We are not looking for an error in the code - we are looking for the line that's not producing what you expect. For example, right before this line setContentView(R.layout.activity_docselect); does R.layout.activity_docselect resolve to nil? Or is is valid and what you expect? That's just an example but you need to to do troubleshooting and tell us where your code is going wrong.

@Jay sure I'll do some troubleshooting and let you know, btw will it be ok to use queryfilter instead of using OrderedRealmCollection as it is much easier.

Not sure I understand the question; in what context do you want to use queryfilter? An OrderedRealmCollection is a collection of ordered Realm objects which is more organizational than functional. If you can elaborate a bit, I may be able to answer.

@Jay actually i want to display the list of available doctors in a recyclerview which are stored in the mogodb. I was saying we can fetch the data using queryfilter too so will it be okay if i use that?

A realm query uses a queryFilter to define what results are returned. Those results are a Collection of objects - using .find or .asFlow are two options. an OrderedRealmCollection is what's return so asking if it's okay is.... okay. It's largely how it's done.

@Jay so you're saying that i need to return the results using queryFilter and then order them using OrderedRealCollection if I get it right, also sorry for being so dumb

You're not being dumb but reviewing the documentation will help. What I linked says: - There are three types of OrderedRealmCollection; RealmResults and RealmList are live collections... and OrderedRealmCollectionSnapshot. Realm Queries return RealmResults which contains the resultant data. The results are ordered via .sort() function when the query is performed.

example from my app (old version now in kotlin):

insert the directive into the project's build.gradle file
 dependencies {
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.3' }


in the application's build.gradle file, call the plugin with the following directive at the beginning of the file
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

realm initialization
 public class MyApplication extends Application {
     Realm.init(this);
     RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration =
             new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                     .name("default.realm")
                     .schemaVersion(3)
                     .migration(new customRealmMigration())
                     //     .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
                     .build();
     Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration); }



inside the AndroidManifest.xml file
    <application
    android:name="com.sampietro.NaiveAAC.activities.Main.MyApplication"


create class by extending RealmObject
 public class Images extends RealmObject {
 /**
  * word or phrase.
  */
 private String descrizione;
 /**
  * contains the file path (originally contained the uri).
  */
 private String uri;
 /*
  * getter, setter and other methods
  */
 /**
  * get <code>descrizione</code>.
  *
  * @return descrizione string data to get
  */
 public String getDescrizione() {
     return descrizione;
 }
 /**
  * get <code>uri</code>.
  *
  * @return uri string file path to get
  */
 public String getUri() {
     return uri;
 }
 //
 /**
  * set <code>descrizione</code>.
  *
  * @param descrizione string data to set
  */
 public void setDescrizione(String descrizione) {
     this.descrizione = descrizione;
 }
 /**
  * set <code>uri</code>.
  *
  * @param uri string file path to set
  */
 public void setUri(String uri) {
     this.uri = uri;
 } }


After inserting the objects into the database, display the content in my case using a fragment, a adapter and a listview
 public class ImagesFragment extends Fragment {
 public View rootView;
 public TextView textView;
 public Context ctext;
 /**
  * <h1>onFragmentEventListenerSettings</h1>
  * <p><b>onFragmentEventListenerSettings</b>
  * interface used to refer to the Activity without having to explicitly use its class
  * <p>
  *
  * @see #onAttach
  */
 public interface onFragmentEventListenerSettings
 {
 //  insert here any references to the Settings Activity
     void receiveResultSettings(View v);
 }
 //
 public onFragmentEventListenerSettings listener=null;
 /**
  * listener setting for settings activity callbacks and context annotation
  *
  * @see androidx.fragment.app.Fragment#onAttach
  */
 @Override
 public void onAttach (Context context)
 {
     super.onAttach(context);
     Activity activity = (Activity) context;
     //
     listener=(onFragmentEventListenerSettings) activity;
     //
     ctext = context;
 }
 //
 private Realm realm;
 //
 private ListView listView=null;
 private ImagesAdapter adapter;
 /**
  * prepares the ui also using a listview and makes the callback to the activity
  *
  * @see androidx.fragment.app.Fragment#onCreateView
  * @see com.example.a20210823simsim.activities.Graphics.Images
  * @see com.example.a20210823simsim.activities.Graphics.ImagesAdapter
  */
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
     rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_settings_images, container, false);
     // logic of fragment
     realm= Realm.getDefaultInstance();
     // ListView
     // 1) we get a reference to the data structure through the RealmResults class which constitutes
     // the query result set and is an iterable collection accessible with Java constructs:
     // for loop, basic access to position and Iterator.
     // The approach for realm queries is object-oriented.
     // The where method will retrieve the objects from the specified class and the result will
     // be treated with filtrate by other specific methods.
     // At the end of the selection configuration, the findAll method will be invoked to retrieve
     // all the corresponding results.
     // 2) we instantiate an Adapter by assigning it, the collection and the layout related to
     // each single row
     // 3) we retrieve the ListView prepared in the layout and assign it the reference to the adapter
     // which will be your View "supplier".
     RealmResults<Images> results = realm.where(Images.class).findAll();
     //
     listView=(ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview);
     //
     adapter=new ImagesAdapter(ctext, results, listView);
     //
     listView.setAdapter(adapter);
     //
     listener.receiveResultSettings(rootView);
     //
     return rootView;
 } }


 'public class ImagesAdapter extends BaseAdapter    {
 private List<Images> images=null;
 private Context context=null;
 private ListView listview=null;
 private Realm realm;
 public ImagesAdapter(Context context, List<Images> images, ListView listview)
 {
     this.images=images;
     this.context=context;
     this.listview=listview;
     //
     Activity activity = (Activity) context;
     listener=(ImagesAdapter.ImagesAdapterInterface) activity;
 }
 @Override
 public int getCount()
 {
     return images.size();
 }
 @Override
 public Object getItem(int position)
 {
     return images.get(position);
 }
 @Override
 public long getItemId(int position)
 {
     return getItem(position).hashCode();
 }
 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup vg)
 {
     // 1) it is checked if the View passed in input is null and only in this
     // case is initialized with the LayoutInflater.
     // The LayoutInflater structures the View to be created as defined in the
     // XML layout indicated.
     // 2) The data will be taken from the object with the element within
     // the list <Images> of position position retrieved using getItem.
     // 3) the listener for the delete button of the element within
     // the list <Images> of position position is set
     if (v==null)
     {
         v= LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.activity_settings_row, null);
     }
     Images l=(Images) getItem(position);
     TextView txt=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageDescriptionRow);
     txt.setText(l.getDescrizione());
     ImageButton imgbtn=(ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete_image);
     imgbtn.setOnClickListener(clickListenerDeleteImage);
     return v;
 }
 private View.OnClickListener clickListenerDeleteImage=new View.OnClickListener()
 {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v)
     {
         int position=listview.getPositionForView(v);
         // delete image
         realm= Realm.getDefaultInstance();
         RealmResults<Images> results = realm.where(Images.class).findAll();
         realm.beginTransaction();
         Images daCancellare=results.get(position);
         assert daCancellare != null;
         daCancellare.deleteFromRealm();
         realm.commitTransaction();
         listener.reloadImagesFragment();
     }
 }; }
  '



 '<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context=>
 <ListView
         android:id="@+id/listview"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="100dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
         android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
         android:padding="10dp"
         app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageLL"/></androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

 '



I hope it is useful to you

thanks for the answer but i have already done all the steps and i'll look into that for sure and let you know.
